# How can I do logistic correction for boosting

Tags: boosting

Can anyone tell me if logistic correction is the best method to correct the probability of gradient boosting machine?  If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are talking about Additive Logistic Regression http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.51.9525

Comment: Hi iampat and welcome to the site! Would you mind elaborating a little bit on why you're suggesting Additive Logistic Regression and what it is? Even just a few sentences would be great (plus, links with context tend to get far more up votes, so this would help you too :-)